# How do I create a .PDF from selected pages of an existing .PDF?

Tags: pdf, documents

The question is simple: I want to create a .PDF from pages 30-50 of an already existing 100 page .PDF.

What would be the easiest and most professional way to do this?

Comment: The most "professional" way would be to buy a copy of Adobe Acrobat and edit the PDF. But, back in the real world, print to a PDF printer from Reader as @schöppi suggests.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Print it on pdf printer and only select pages 30-50.

Comment: CutePDF would be one such PDF Printer.

Comment: Do you mean physically print it? I need a digital copy :)

Comment: No, open print dialogue and select a pdf printer. Such as CutePDF as mentioned by Force Flow, or Adobe Acrobat

Comment: CutePDF is extremely annoying nagware. For a completely free, non-nag, open-source PDF virtual printer for Windows, see PDFcreator http://en.pdfforge.org/

Comment: How is CutePDF nagware? I've been using it for years and I've never been nagged. Actually, a lot of people complain that PDFcreator installs toolbars even when told not to - http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/reviews/

Answer (score 3):

I haven't used this but it looks interesting and offers a lot of other options as well:

> [PDF Split and Merge](http://www.pdfsam.org/)

Comment: It is my "go to" tool for working with PDF pages.

Answer (score 2):

There are two commandline tools, both available for Linux as well as for Windows or Mac OS X, which can do this:

- [**PDFTK**](http://www.pdflabs.com/docs/install-pdftk/)
- [**Ghostscript**](http://www.ghostscript.com/releases/)

Using **pdftk/pdftk.exe:**

```
pdftk mypdf.pdf cat 30-50 output mypdf-pages-30-50.pdf
```

Using **gs/gswin32c.exe:**

```
gswin32c.exe ^
 -o mypdf-pages-30-50.pdf ^
 -sDEVICE=pdfwrite ^
 -dFirstPage=30 ^
 -dLastPage=50 ^
 -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress ^
  c:/path/to/mypdf.pdf
```

(The **gswin32.exe** command is the example for Windows usage. On Linux, replace this with **gs** and type the complete command on one line, or replace the line-continue chars `^` by `\`.)

Answer (score 0):

I use the [Bullzip PDF Printer](http://www.bullzip.com/products/pdf/info.php), and have found it to be very reliable and reasonably configurable for a free product.